# Storing multiple item settings in database

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I'm building a gallery. Each image is a row with name and src and order etc.

I want to have 3 more options per image: Featured, Visible, Disabled.

Should I have those as columns?

Or have just 1 column settings and store a 3 binary numbers?

For example:

111 = Featured, Visible, Disabled

110 = Featured, Visible

010 = Visible

001 =  Disabled

Or I can even convert that to DEC and simply store a 0 to 7 (like CHMOD style)

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "best".  Unless you have considerable (and *measurable*) performance concerns, I'd recommend going with the *simplest* approach.  Which would be well-named and defined columns.  If the requirements change, update from there.  But there's no need to do something overly clever without specific reason.

Comment: Separate columns for sure; go with simplicity. I'd recommend `CHAR(1)` with values of `Y` or `N`. Everybody will understand that. If you have 10 million rows you'll use a paltry 10 Mb more disk space than the bit approach. That's not really a tradeoff at all.

Comment: Thank you both. That's exactly what I needed to know. I just didn't know if multiple rows were more expensive than characters in a single row. I'll go with simplicity.

Comment: The reason I got confused was because I was reading about [Reddit's database which only has 2 tables](https://kev.inburke.com/kevin/reddits-database-has-two-tables/)  (things & data) and "claims" to perform better than using rows. Idk though ()

Comment: Stick with tried, tested, and formalized approaches unless you a) really know what you're doing, and b) really *need* to break the rules or switch paradigm. There's an adage about premature optimization being the root of all evil - i.e. worrying about performance issues you don't actually have can lead you astray. Learn about normalization, and stick with those rules as much as possible while you're working in a transactional, relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends. are only programmers with pocket-protectors looking at data and app code? i am all for complexity but i would say spring for a little overhead. also, despite valiant efforts, i have failed to do bit-wise searching in mysql

Problems with bit-wise searching, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352263/optimize-mysql-query-to-use-index-on-a-bitwise-where-clause).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to store/manipulate in MySQL...

- `SET ('Featured', 'Visible', 'Disabled')`
- `TINYINT UNSIGNED` and do bit arithmetic; see `1 << 2` give you 4; 0x4 is a way to express literal 4 in hex; `a | b` is bitwise OR, etc.